Make URL Rewrites to work for Ignored Routes in Web API
I have an ASP.NET Web API in .NET Framework and I specifically want to make my URL rewrites work for the routes which are ignored by IgnoreRoute method
config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Rewrite urls to be ignored", "api/v1/config/routetoforward");

Rewrite rule:
<rule name="Rewrite URLs" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="api/v1/config/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://example2.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true"/>
</rule>

But instead of forwarding to rewrite it, I get this error:

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://example.com/api/v1/config/routetoforward'.
MessageDetail: No route data was found for this request.

Can someone help in finding out what is the actual issue here and how can I make ignored routes to be handled with URL rewrites?
